# How to fix "KeyError: '*' " in elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement elasticsearch in my project, but I got this error when I tried to run this command `python manage.py index_orders`

I've tried changing the elasticsearch version to the latest one (7.1.1) and run it.

This is my command class which I'm trying to run

**index_orders.py**

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Indexes Orders in Elastic Search'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        es = Elasticsearch(
            [{'host': settings.ES_HOST, 'port': settings.ES_PORT}],
            index="order"
        )
        order_index = Index('order')
        order_index.doc_type(OrderDoc)
        if order_index.exists():
            order_index.delete()
            print('Deleted order index.')
        OrderDoc.init()
        result = bulk(
            client=es,
            actions=(order.indexing() for order in Order.objects.all().iterator())
        )
        print('Indexed orders.')
        print(result)
```

This is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 30, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/blowhorn/order/management/commands/index_orders.py", line 26, in handle
    OrderDoc.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/document.py", line 138, in init
    i.save(using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/index.py", line 289, in save
    current_settings = self.get_settings(using=using)[self._name]['settings']['index']
KeyError: '*'
```

Comment: Can you provide the elasticsearch **JSON** queries generated ? There is too much missing information in the provided code. Also, if you are using es7, the doc_type property is deprecated.

Comment: @Pierre-NicolasMougel thanks..........the error has been resolved

Comment: Good to hear, thanks for your reply